# how to set the number of tasks per node to 1

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, numbers, task

How can I modify the number of tasks in hadoop 2.6 in each node?
I find that we have to use `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` and `yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores`.

I want to use just a 1 task per node. Should I configure the xml files to do that?what is the specific configuration?.

or we  just mention the value of `mapreduce.job.maps` to 1?

If I use hadoop version 1.2, do I just have to modify this parameter in mapred-site
 `mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` with value 1?

Comment: I tried to make your question more readable, but please edit again, if I ruined something.

Comment: thanks it s very good i dont speak english so i appologize for any mistakes..

is there any answer for my questions?@vefthym

Comment: or i want a link for a semilar Questions that resolved may helped me

Comment: i will change the version of hadoop 2.6 to hadoop 1.2 because  it containt this property:mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum so i can set it to 1 (and this what i needed (one task per node) ...

Answer (score 0):

In MR1, the mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum and mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum properties dictated how many map and reduce slots each TaskTracker had.

These properties no longer exist in YARN. Instead, YARN uses yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb and yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores, which control the amount of memory and CPU on each node, both available to both maps and reduces.

Essentially:
YARN has no TaskTrackers, but just generic NodeManagers. Hence, there's no more Map slots and Reduce slots separation. Everything depends on the amount of memory in use/demanded

Using the web UI you can get lot of monitoring/admin kind of info:

NameNode - http://:50070/ 
Resource Manager - http://:8088/

Comment: i changed the version to 1.2  i hope :
`mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum` resolve problem